# how can I upload file in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have problem while trying to upload file.
I use mongo as database and reactjs for frontend.
file appears in the database but it does not appear in the project.
I wanna appear in the directory which I set in the code.
And this is backend API.

```
const express = require("express");
const fileRoutes = express.Router();
let File = require("../../models/File");
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const storageBase = require("../../config/keys").storageBase;
const isEmpty = require("is-empty");
const addDays = require("date-fns").addDays;
const moment = require("moment-timezone");
// const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
// app.use(fileUpload());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const { file_type, file_owner } = req.query;
    const path =
      `${storageBase}` +
      `${file_type}/${moment(new Date()).tz("Asia/Shanghai").format("YYYY-MM/MM-DD")}/${file_owner}`;
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
      fs.mkdirsSync(path);
    }
    cb(null, path);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits:{
    files: 5,
    fieldSize: 4096 * 1024 * 1024
  }
});

fileRoutes
  .route("/upload")
  .post(upload.single("file_data"), function (req, res) {
    const {
      file_type,
      file_description1,
      file_description2,
      file_description3,
      file_owner,
      file_owner_job,
      file_register_date,
      hour,
      minute
    } = req.query;
    let file = new File({
      file_type: file_type,
      file_url: req.query.file_register_date + "/" + req.files.file_data.name,
      file_description1: file_description1,
      file_description2: file_description2,
      file_description3: file_description3,
      file_owner: file_owner,
      file_owner_job: file_owner_job,
      file_register_date: file_register_date + " " + hour + ":" + minute
    });
  
    file
      .save()
      .then(file => {
        res.status(200).json({ file: "file uploaded successfully" });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("upload failed");
      });
  });

module.exports = fileRoutes;
```

But file which I select for upload does not save in my project
If u know how to do pls help me.

Comment: Have you set the enctype as multipart/form-data in the front end?

Comment: onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file_owner", this.state.file_owner);
    formData.append("file_owner_job", this.state.file_owner_job);
    // file data
    formData.append("file_data", this.state.file_selected);

    axios
      .post("/api/files/upload", formData, {
      ---

Comment: It seems like FormData() by default sets enctype to multipart/form-data, so this is fine.            However, the way you are sending the image "file_data", is it fine ?                                      Check https://javascript.info/formdata once . You might need to use body: new FormData(formElem) , where formElem is id of the form or  use formData.append(name, blob, fileName)    .Please check once.